# How to show field from a table that connects another table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Project model that can contain many Products through the model Benefit (and vice versa for the Product model). Within the Benefits tabel a project_id and product_id are uniquely indexed.

I've created the Benefit model to be able to add a product to multiple projects and I want to add extra data through every benefit (benefit.title etc.).

I'm able to show the products per project, but I'm not able to show any other benefit.value.

My Project model is connected to Benefits like this:

```
has_many :benefits
has_many :products, through: :benefits
```

In my Project view (show.html.erb) I'm showing my product field like this:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
                    <%= link_to [product.project, product] do %>    
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col m3">
                                    <img height="20" src="<%= product.image %>"></img>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col m3">
                                    <%= product.name %>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col m3 truncate">
                                    <%= product.content %>
                                </div>                                  
                                <div class="col m3">
                                    <i class="tiny red-text material-icons right">favorite_border</i>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
```

But it tells me that I'm using an undefined local variable or method 'Benefit', when I try to add the following:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
                    <%= link_to [product.project, product] do %>    
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col m3">
                                    <img height="20" src="<%= product.image %>"></img>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col m3">
                                    <%= product.name %>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col m3 truncate">
                                    <%= benefit.title %>
                                </div>                                  
                                <div class="col m3">
                                    <i class="tiny red-text material-icons right">favorite_border</i>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
```

Any ideas on how I should handle this?

I'm using Ruby-on-Rails 4.2.0 and I'm a novice (as you can clearly see ;) )

Extra code of my product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]

belongs_to :project

belongs_to :benefit

has_many :subscriptions
has_many :users, through: :subscriptions

has_many :benefits
has_many :projects, through: :benefits

has_many :reviews

validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
validates :gtin, presence: true
validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
validates :video, presence: true
validates :tag, presence: false
validates :project, presence: true

has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "680x300>", :thumb => "170x75>" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

def average_rating
    reviews.blank? ? 0 : reviews.average(:star).round(2)
end
end
```

*Update Working code: Based on the comments in this question I was able to show a list of products (that are connected to the project) with any benefit-field connected to it. I created an extra loop by mistake, that's solved now. Here's my final working code in my `project/show.html.erb`:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
                <% product.benefits.each do |benefit| %>
                    <%= link_to [product.project, product] do %>    
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col m3">
                                    <img height="20" src="<%= product.image %>"></img>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col m3">
                                    <%= product.name %>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col m3 truncate">
                                    <%= product.benefits.first.title %>
                                </div>                                  
                                <div class="col m3">
                                    <i class="tiny red-text material-icons right">favorite_border</i>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
```

Comment: The answer below is correct you need to use the `product` variable as the reciever since the block is not executed in the context of `product`. That being said I am not sure how you are loading this data but unless you are performing an eager load of some kind (e.g. `eager_load`, `include`, etc.) to load this data before hand you are going to end up with a painful n + 1 issue here where it has to execute a query to lookup the project and another to find all the benefits for each product individually on each iteration.

Comment: Not loading the data could definitely be the problem. I'm connecting projects in the same way to a subscription model with users. I am able to get user fields in it and I can't seem to find the difference in settings. Are there simple tutorials outthere to learn how to load the proper data?

Comment: [This Article](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html) has some great information on how rails query methods work and how the data will be loaded on execution in reagrds to `joins`, `eager_load`, `preload`, and `include`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
In this issue, you have to loop each benefits form product because you can't get has many associations at one.

You have to use object product to call benefit. Try this to loop each benefit:

```
<%= product.benefits.each | benefit| %>
  <div class="col m3 truncate">
    <%= benefit.title %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Try this to get first product benefit:

```
<%= product.benefits.first.title %>
```

This is to get all benefit join (,):

```
<%= product.benefits.map(&:title).join(", ") %>
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't seem to work, it returns:

undefined method `benefit' for #<Product:0x007ffc87c3c158>

Comment: @SebastianPlasschaert is it possible you do not have a relationship for product that says that a product belongs to a `benefit`? This seems to be the case based on your error. You have not posted anything pertaining to the `Product` model so it is difficult to determine exactly where the issue is here.

Comment: Thanks so far @engineersmnky
I've added the project model to the initial question. The **belongs_to :benefit** I've added based on your comments. It doesn't give an error, but is doesn't work either.
The original model already has a **has_many :benefits
has_many :projects, through: :benefits**, so I hoped that that was good enough as an eager load...

Comment: In this case, you have to choose what benefit should be showed in your div. I have updated my answer. I hope those help you.

Comment: Thanks @MuhamadAkbarBinWidayat!, that worked for the most part: very cool!
The only problem that I have now is that for every product connected to the project, it will show the product another time if there's another benefit connection between that product and any other project.
I'm going to read the join-part of the article that @engineersmnky provided: I don't know how to use the join-code that you suggested...
If you guys have any tips for that last tweak, please let me know! ;)

Comment: `<%= product.benefits.each | benefit| %>` should not have an `=` eg. `<% product.benefits.each | benefit| %>` otherwise it will print the whole collection of benefits for each product after the iteration. @SebastianPlasschaert maybe post another question about the most efficient way to load the information you want as it does not really pertain to this question anymore.

Comment: I already figured that out, the `=` is not in my code, but it still gives double products.

But I completely agree @engineersmnky, that's another question. Thanks for your effort, you and @Muhamad were a big help for my very first Stackoverflow question/experience ;)

Comment: ...and now I was able to fix it. Thank! The final code is updatet above.

Comment: @SebastianPlasschaert glad it worked out. Do not forget to remove `belongs_to :benefit` that was a misunderstanding of the design of the application and could have negative impacts if it remains in place.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help. @engineersmnky: Thank's for you revision and correction. :)